# ssh-keygen -lf doesn't work in 16.04 LTS

Tags: ssh, 16.04

When I run the command `ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key` it returns:

```
2048 SHA256 asdfgErgsf34GQERgfdGadsfsafgergfgadgfagjfaifgj root@Fre2 (RSA)
```

Instead of a value such as:

```
RSA key fingerprint is c5:28:29:b9:44:d7:b1:4c:72:6f:3f:d2:fd:69:11:49
```

Is this broken in 16.04?

Comment: Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/929566/sha256-ssh-fingerprint-given-by-the-client-but-only-md5-fingerprint-known-for-se

Comment: Its a feature. You don't want to stick with md5 forever.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the default output has changed, and the default fingerprint hash upgraded to SHA256.

To get an output in MD5 format, use the `-E` switch:

```
$ ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
2048 MD5:c5:28:29:b9:44:d7:b1:4c:72:6f:3f:d2:fd:69:11:49 no comment (RSA)
```

Comment: That's what the manpage says! :-)

Comment: Oh, and welcome to AskUbuntu!   Please click the "Accept Answer" tick (under the up-down arrows) if you consider this the correct answer to your question.